# Maximum entropy probability distribution derivation (Information theory and statistical mechanics, ET. Jaynes)

Tags: probability, lagrange-multiplier, information-theory, entropy

I am going through the paper "[Information theory and statistical mechanics](https://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/theory.1.pdf)" by E.T. Jaynes, and at equation (2-4), he derives the probability distribution to maximize entropy given we know the expectation value of the function $f(x)$ as such using Lagrange multipliers:
$$
p_i = e^{- \lambda-\mu f(x_i)}
$$

When maximizing the Shannon entropy, we want to maximize equation (2-3):
$$
H(p_1 ... p_n) = -K\sum_i p_i ln(p_i)
$$
while subject to the constraints, known expectation value of $f(x)$ in equations (2-1), and normalization condition (2-2):

Equation (2-1)
$$
\langle f(x) \rangle = \sum_i p_i f(x_i)
$$

Equation (2-2)
$$
\sum_i p_i = 1
$$

I try to derive (2-4) in the steps below:
Using Lagrange multipliers $\lambda$ and $\mu$
$$
L = -K\sum_i p_i ln(p_i) - \lambda(\sum_i p_i - 1) - \mu (\sum_i p_i f(x_i) - \langle f(x) \rangle)
$$

Solving for stationary point of $L$
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial p_i} = -K(ln(p_i) + 1) - \lambda - \mu f(x_i) = 0
$$

Using $K=1$ as used by Jaynes
$$
ln(p_i) = - \lambda - \mu f(x_i) - 1
$$

$$
p_i = e^{- \lambda - \mu f(x_i) - 1}
$$

Now, why was the $-1$ term in the exponent not present in equation (2-4)?

Comment: you can absorb the $-1$ into $\lambda$

Comment: @Kakashi, oh man, that was such a simple reason... Thanks!